# “Please select a site specific close reason” when casting a “keep closed” vote in the review queue

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-reopen

I got this when I wanted to vote for a question to remain closed:

[image: A popup saying “Please select a site specific close reason” above a “Why should this question remain closed?” modal, where the last option, “This uestion doesn’t meet a Retrocomputing Stack Exchange guideline.” is selected.]

I picked the last option (intending to pick the generic off-topic reason), since I feel like the question ought to remain closed, although for a different reason than what it was closed in the first place.  If this vote reason cannot be selected, why is it displayed at all?

Posting this here, as I suspect this is a bug in the software, not exclusive to the Retrocomputing site (though I have no way to reproduce it anywhere else).  [The feature](/q/270647/620615) seems to work fine on Stack Overflow, though; I suspect this is the only site where it was tested.

Comment: Looks like the site simply does not have site specific close reasons, so I don't think it's a bug. Not sure who can add those and how, but once there will be site specific close reasons, they will appear when closing and when voting for a question to remain closed, as happens in sites having such reasons.

Comment: @Shadow that could still be seen as a bug, it would make sense if every site has the "This question does not fall within the scope of [Site Name] as defined in the help center" as a default option within the category of "doesn't meet a [Site Name] guideline".

Comment: @Marijn perhaps, but then it's bigger scope than just the close/leave closed dialog and better be posted as a separate feature request.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Just because a workaround exists doesn’t make it not a bug.